# CSS3/Javascript: Transitions IE support using jQuery/Modernizr

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, modernizr

Does anyone know how I could achieve IE 7-9 support for [(this in Codepen.io)](http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/FltaL) button hover effect?

eg specifically:

```
transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
margin-top: 5px;
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098856/using-modernizr-and-jquery-to-animate-if-css3-transitions-dont-exist), however, margin-top will not animate. Others seem to..

What am I doing wrong?? Grateful for any help.

I have jQuery, Modernizr...

Thanks A lot

Harley

(Apologies in advance if this is a blatant duplicate, just I seem to have a particular problem)

Comment: Why would you need CSS transitions when using jQuery's animate. Using both seems like strangeness waiting to happen?

Comment: Don't know if it's just me, but IE 8 is having trouble loading the codepen interface.

Comment: @adeneo I think he want's jQuery animate as a fallback, not simultaneously.

Comment: @Asad Yes I do want it as a fallback. (Oh and IE9 does load it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$(this).animate({margin-top:'5px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
```

You'll either need to quote the CSS value or use camelcase:

```
$(this).animate({marginTop:'5px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
$(this).animate({'margin-top':'5px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
```

This pretty much applies to all CSS values with hyphens etc.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. You're right. Thanks. Out of interest, **why** is that?

Comment: @harley - the 'why' is because without the quotes, `margin-top` is invalid Javascript code (it sees the hyphen as a minus sign, not part of the property name).

Comment: @harley css properties are exposed to the DOM under camel cased and non hyphenated property names.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks- so it thinks Its a chunk of maths   You learn summat every day.