# Detecting slow hardware/slow browsers with JavaScript

Tags: css, browser, javascript

My website has several CSS animations and transitions, all of which render very, very slowly in certain browsers (thankfully, not most of them), and with certain older hardware. I'm trying to avoid UA sniffing; is there any way to detect browsers or hardware configurations using a JavaScript, or a JS library, and subsequently load non-animated versions for browsers which I know don't have good support for those features?

Just to clear up any ambiguity, I'm not looking for something like Modernizr.

Comment: I would suggest writing some timing detection yourself, for your specific needs.  "Slow" is too much of a generalization, especially when certain devices and hardware have accelerations for specific features.

Comment: I'd rather provide an option for the user to disable such animations than going through the hassle of detecting "slow hardware" which may not be accurate to the user's liking.

Comment: @FabricioMatte: while giving the user more flexibility is admirable, if something were *really* slow on my box and was not a critical item (i.e. banking/bill payment) I would not bother looking for ways to disable it but rather kill the tab on the spot.

Comment: Get a list of the MOST common slow devices' useragent string and check for that on page-load. for example: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings (only for mobile/tablets since slow computer have no unique useragent identifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means sufficient to *detect* a slow system, but would minimize the impact on the users of such systems:

[Use CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and trigger them with jQuery (by toggling classes as needed), offloading element animations to the rendering engine so that functional responsiveness of the page would not suffer at least.

Use the *correct* CSS properties. For instance, rather than animating `top:10px;left:10px;` properties, use a [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) `transform: translateX(10px) translateY(10px)` which will be more efficient.

Trigger hardware (GPU) acceleration by adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` or a similar workaround to the target element.

If you're absolutely attached to animations, or need to trigger fallback functionality (hide/show/reposition elements) without CSS for some reason, [you could try a Modernizr workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114103/1081234):

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
  /*fallback logic*/
}
```

Comment: I do use CSS transitions and transforms, and am familiar with the technology. Could you elaborate on triggering the transitions and transforms with jQuery?

Comment: @Verandaguy: I mean jQuery could be used to adjust "final" property values (that are being animated towards) as opposed to iteratively adjusting "intermediate" property values. Maybe this is better explained in [a thorough example](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/css-animation/)?